# facebook friend selector

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi
I am working on an iframe based facebook application, I want to develop an auto complete friend selector, but I think it is already provided by facebook? So is that already exist or I need to use JQuery autocomplete? In any case please tell that what facebook provides to developers? What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/). You will find many examples including friend selector, and you can run them from your browser

Answer (score 2):

There also exist two JQuery Plugins you might be interested in. The first is an autocomplete plugin which includes a Facebook theme and the second is a full friend selector plugin. I already used both on production:
http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html (see the facebook theme)
http://labs.thesedays.com/blog/2011/06/20/the-missing-facebook-interface-component-for-friend-selection/

Answer (score 0):

Friend selector still exists - albeit rather clunky - Check out [serverFbml](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/serverFbml/) which serves as a wrapper of the legacy friend-selector

Example:

```
<fb:serverFbml style="width: 755px;">  
     <script type="text/fbml">
        <fb:fbml>
            <fb:request-form
                action="<URL for post invite action, see fb:request-form docs for details>"
                method="POST"
                invite="true"
                type="XFBML"
                content="This is a test invitation from XFBML test app
                <fb:req-choice url="see fb:req-choice docs for details."
                    label="Ignore the Facebook test app!" />
             ">
             </fb:request-form>
                <fb:multi-friend-selector
                    showborder="false"
                    actiontext="Invite your friends to use Facebook." />
         </fb:fbml>
    </script>
</fb:serverFbml>
```

Comment: I was already using this and didn't want to use this, I think you haven't read question carefully. I have asked for autocomplete option in a text box